# SSH tunnel local port forwarding to Facebook over HTTPS

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, facebook

I successfully establish connection to https sites over SSH Tunnel local port forwarding. But I can not reach to Facebook in the same way. What can be the restriction?

The ssh command I use;

```
ssh -L 9001:www.facebook.com:443 RemoteServerIP
```

The URL I browse;

```
https://localhost:9001
```

Comment: Your ssh command is incomplete, you surely cannot ssh to it this way. What is the command you really use, and which reply do you get? Second, what is the exact error message you have? (No facebook account, no way for me to try it myself).

Comment: @MariusMatutiae you are right. I added **RemoteServerIP** to the command. The error message is "page not found" after SSL security warning.

Comment: Many Websites have an IP address corresponding to www.myname.com, but then they redirect you to another IP address to provide their service. They often do this in order to be faster, so that they have many servers located all over the world, rather than just a single centralized service. On the basis of your trivial error message, I bet this is what is happening.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae your comment is good enough to be answer. Please write it as a reply then i am going to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Websites have an IP address corresponding to www.myname.com, but then they redirect you to another IP address to provide their service.

They often do this in order to be faster, so that they have many servers located all over the world, rather than just a single centralized service. On the basis of your trivial error message,

I bet this is what is happening.